# Cross language support in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, python, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

I am working with several different services which have been written in Python and Java. I have now come to the point where I need to have these services communicate with each other and ActiveMQ seems to be a sensible choice.

However, I am not sure I quite follow the concept of the different protocols available for ActiveMQ. The main question being, do I have to implement all my services to use the same protocol for accessing the bus?

1. Is it possible to run the same bus with multiple different connection protocols concurrently?
2. If yes to 1. Is it just connection to the bus which is governed by a Protocol or does the protocol choice also influence the type of the actual message content. I.e. will it be possible to post a message from Java JMS to a topic and have a Python STOMP client read that message correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inter language interopability can be made by different clients using the same protocol, such as JMS for Java, CMS for C++ and NMS for .NET (when it comes to OpenWire). I don't think there is a great OpenWire Python client out there, except some [CMS wrappers](https://code.google.com/p/pyactivemq/).

On the other hand, ActiveMQ does a great job to bridge between different protocols so that they can share the same queues/topics. It works really well to read stomp, MQTT and AMQP messages sent from OpenWire/JMS. Please be aware that you may want to avoid advanced features of say JMS like MapMessage, rely on specific JMS headers and stick to simple text messages or byte messages. The bridge is not 100% transparent, but as I said, does a great job.

So, you can go with stomp or even AMQP 1.0, some instruction from Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj841070.aspx).